# Counting characters within a string

Tags: java

Hey I had an interview question earlier, and the first image shows what it asked me. The second being my attempt. In the attempt, I unfortunately didn't complete it correctly.

But, I was looking for guidance on how far off I was from their desired solution. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So did you debug it or what?

Comment: You are reading from STDIN, while task says "command line arguments"

Comment: Please post _code_ instead of screen shots of code.

Comment: this was done through a web exam so I don't have the code in an IDE. I will re-write it out and post it up within 10 minutes, apologise @MickMnemonic

Comment: With web exam, you can always copy the actual contents.  Ctrl-A / Ctrl-C.  If they are running some JavaScript to prevent that, you can always View Source.

Comment: Are you really interviewing for a programming job without being able to count characters in a string?

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that you aren't looping over characters. `character` is literally only set once, always to `array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The supplied code had three problems:

1. It wasn't incrementing the counter when it found a 2nd (or 3rd) occurrence of a letter. You caught that one by adding the `+ 1`.
2. Notice that the required output was all lowercase. They wanted you to treat uppercase letters as if they were lowercase, suggesting that you should probably put a `.toLowerCase()` in there somewhere if the Key values of your TreeMap are case-sensitive. (Hint: They are.)
3. Notice that your sample output, `105=I,` has the number first and the character second. `TreeMap<Character,Integer>` tells you that the `Character` is the Key and the `Integer` is the Value. The `System.out.print` has them reversed.

(Bonus hint: The looping structure in the original question is essentially correct. You don't need a `for (int i = 0; ...` loop structure.)